# iOS: After app update my app crashes because of new cell in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an iPhone app in the app store, which has in the settings menu a section with 4 cells (grouped static cells).

I have added now one new cell to this section. When I update the version from the App Store using Xcode, my app crashes when I want to open the settings menu.

The app has a problem with the new cell, because I get this exception when I want to get to the settings menu: Terminating app due to uncaught exception `'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'`

When I set the return value in the method `"numberOfRowsInSection"` back to 4, I can launch the app without any problem, but certainly without the new row.

And now the unbelievable event: When I delete the app from my iPhone and load it completely new with Xcode on my iPhone, than everything is fine and the app loads the new row without any complications. Apparently there is a problem in the update process...

Did anyone have an idea? I don't want to submit the new version and everybody gets crashes when updating the app :(

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here is the stacktrace
http://www.nucro.de/stacktrace.tiff

EDIT2: Here the code that initializes the settings (NSUserDefaults)

```
- (void)initializeData {
    if (self.dataInitialized == 1) {
        return;
    }
    self.pillMode = 0;
    self.pillReminder = @"alle 30 min.";
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [components setHour:20];
    [components setMinute:0];
    self.activeSwitch = YES;
    self.fadeInEffectEnabled = YES;
    self.timeReminder = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    self.messageReminder = NSLocalizedString(@"MainViewController_defaultnotif_message", @"");
    self.soundReminder = @"cartoonconga";//@"Standardton";
    self.cycleDay = 1;
    self.blister = 1;
    self.totalDayAmount = 1;
    self.protocol = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self.protocol addObject:[self newCycleObject]];
    self.firstUse = YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Core Data or do you store arrays in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Or are you using resources/sqlite?

Comment: Please show datasource code. I think you return wrong data

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I use NSUSerDefaults. But the Array with the Exception is an Array of the TableView. The array where the Rows are stored (I think). This is definitely not an data array of me.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: It is definitely related to indexpath.row. Have you added the element for row 5 to the array that originally feeds the cell (cell data).

Comment: There isn't an array that feeds the cell. The cells are Static cells, designed in the storyboard. @murat I have added an link for an image of the stacktrace

Comment: That stack trace is not very useful. Please add an exception breakpoint as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) and post the stack trace when the breakpoint is hit. It will show you the exact line that is causing the exception.

Comment: That stack trace looks like it has some frames hidden. There should be a slider at the bottom of the sidebar where the stack trace is shown. Please slide that so that the maximum number of frames is shown (should be 16 frames with "__pthread_kill" being the first frame and "start" being the last frame)

Comment: Can you also include the code that initializes the settings to the default values? I wonder how you set contents of the NSUserDefaults when the application has launched for the first time.

Comment: @murat I have added an exception breakpoint: The exception is thrown in the viewWillAppear, after I call [self.tableView reloadData]. But when I delete that line, the exception is still thrown, but without stoping at a line (directly to that "stacktrace" I have uploaded). I uploaded a new version of the stack trace. The code taht initializes the settings I add in a few minutes.

Comment: It looks like `initializeData` is just initializing your view controller. There is not any use of `NSUserDefaults` at all.

Comment: initializeData is called only once at the very first launch of the app, never called again (only directly after download from the App Store). initializeData is only for setting default values, after the call of initializeData a saveData is called, where the data stored with NSUserDefault. Could it be really possible that this is the problem?

Comment: It's like CodeMonkey said, there is a problem with the indexpath.row. He can't find a cell behind indexPath.row = 4 in this section. But I don't understand why... Like I said, there is no DataArray from me, that feeds the section with rows. The tableview is only filled with Static Cells, designed in the story board and in the storyboard the new cell is listed.

Comment: Thanks to everybody :) But I have found the bug. The problem was that my (updated) Storyboard wasn't compiled or anything like that. The app has still used the old storyboard, for whatever reason. I have deleted the storyboard from the project and imported it again, now everything is fine! :)